# I'm looking to copy a part of another website and paste it in mine

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex, ajax

I'm looking to copy a part of another website and paste it in mine, can i use iframe to take just an element by his id?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no the iframe tag api is :

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

in the src you need to provide a url

what you want to do is called [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

and it probebly wont even work as you want .
because you need the css file 
for the element to look the same as the other website 
and provide same DOM hierarchy as well